# C++ returns NaN after a sum

Tags: c++, nan, trigonometry

[image]I'm running the following code:

```
    double Scos [61][61][61] = {0};
    double kdotr;
    int ik;
    int howmany [34] = {0};
    auto Fs_ = initializer_list<int>({0});
    copy(Fs_.begin(), Fs_.end(), Fs);

    for ( size_t z=0; z<5; ++z )
    {
        for ( size_t y=0; y<5; ++y )
        {
            for ( size_t x=0; x<10; ++x )
            {
                for ( int k1=0; k1<=60; ++k1 )
                {
                    for ( int k2=0; k2<=60; ++k2 )
                    {
                        for ( int k3=0; k3<=60; ++k3 )
                        {
                            int i = x+y*10+z*50;
                            kdotr = (double)dQ*( (k1-30)*(x_[i][0]-x) + (k2-30)*(x_[i][1]-y) + (k3-30)*(x_[i][2]-z) );
                            if ( isnan(kdotr) )
                                cout << "kdotr " << k1 << " " << k2 << " " << k3 << endl;
                            Scos[k1][k2][k3] += (double)cos(kdotr);
                            if ( isnan(Scos[k1][k2][k3]) )
                                cout << "Scos "  << k1 << " " << k2 << " " << k3 << endl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for ( int k1=0; k1<=60; ++k1 )
    {
        for ( int k2=0; k2<=60; ++k2 )
        {
            for ( int k3=0; k3<=60; ++k3 )
            {
                double k = (double)dQ*sqrt( pow((k1-30),2) + pow((k2-30),2) + pow((k3-30),2) );
                ik = round(k/0.1);
                Fs[ik] += Scos[k1][k2][k3];
                if ( isnan(Fs[ik]) )
                    cout << "Fs[ik] " << k1 << " " << k2 << " " << k3 << endl;
                ++howmany[ik];
            }
        }
    }
```

At the beginning there are just some declarations and initializations (array `Fs` was already declared somewhere else, together with `dQ` and `x_`).

I put calls to `isnan` because the code strangely returns some NaNs. At first, I believed the problem was with `kdotr` going to infinity, which would have been argument of `cos`; however, the code never fails at `Scos`, but at some `Fs[ik]`. This does not make sense to me, since `Fs` comes from a simple sum (and it is initialized to 0).

Has ever happened to you to obtain `NaN` after a sum between finite terms in C++?

Comment: No, it never happened for me. On the other hand, I never had 5 for loops one within another.

Comment: The common cause for "NaN" is that one of your other calculations use NaN as input (or do math that goes wrong and result in NaN). I suspect some of your data is incorrectly initialized.

Comment: @BЈовић: Do you think this can cause some problems with NaN?

Comment: what is the objective of this code? 5 nested loops....

Comment: You deal with a complex algorithm. Therefore try to break and simplify it as much as possible. As Mat suggested, you most likely wrongly initializes something.

Comment: can you use `memset` to initialize all your arrays to 0 and then see if you still get NaN?

Comment: kdotr never initialized? Why?

Comment: @Bill: Well, I could avoid the outer three. The first three refer to particle positions in 3D (which are stored in a 1D array), while the other are varying components of scattering wavevectors.

Comment: I'll try with `memset` and avoiding the three outer loops.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Why should it be a problem?

Comment: @Pippo: You may be applying that long formula to an unknown memory position. Even keyboard may be changing that area.

Comment: The point you should take from BЈовић is not that you should not nest 5 loops, but that complex code is easy to get wrong. If you have 5 nested loops, then it is quite easy to loose track of what you are doing. There are other funny things in the code, for example, the use of `Fs` with the `copy` algorithm out of a *single* value... what is it that you are trying to do? Can you explain it in simple terms? Can you describe the logic in terms of smaller subproblems? Can you refactor the code into those subproblems and verify that each part works before mixing it all together? Do you need casts?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: The first access to that particular variable is always a write, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: As of the original question, no you should never get a `NaN` as the result of a sum of terms, some argument to the sum must be a `NaN` to generate that result.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas `+inf + -inf` would produce a NaN, but it doesn't look like that would happen here.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Actually, the use of `copy` is a silly way to initialize `Fs`, which is member of a class (all this code is part of a method of this class). The problem is that the terms which I am summing shouldn't be infinite. About the casts, you are right, I can remove them.

Comment: @Pippo: Make sure that all inputs of the sum are correct, *infinity* and *NaN* are not the same. Either you are accessing the wrong address in memory, or the array from which you read has not been initialized correctly.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It is very strange. Now I'm using `memset` and I still get the same problem. My only idea is that, since it should be used a large amount of memory for this code, maybe the cluster I'm using cannot handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem is ALWAYS caused by some input to a calculation either being "invalid" (leading to the FPU generating a NaN as the result) or using "NaN" as an input in itself.

In this case, having a quick scan through the operations you do, it seems like there are only operations that don't generate NaN based on (for example) negative inputs [like sqrt or log would do], so my thinking is that one or more of your inputs are reading uninitialized (or incorrectly initialized) data.

I would start by checking that all the components of:

```
 x_[i][0]-x) + (k2-30)*(x_[i][1]-y) + (k3-30)*(x_[i][2]-z
```

are not `NaN`. In particular `x_[i][0,1,2]`.

Since your code is not a complete piece of exectutable code, and some variable's initialization isn't even in the code-snippet, it will be impossible for anyone here to give you a precise answer to where in your code it is going wrong.

Comment: But if there would be problems with `kdotr`, why `Scos` is never seen as a NaN?

Comment: About the executable code, you are very right, but the original code is a complete molecular dynamics (it's pretty huge).

Comment: Assuming this is a x87 machine, then there's no way that `Fs[ik]` can be NaN without `Scos` being NaN, except for corruption of the actual data entries. I would add code to inspect the input value when it goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you, Mats. The problem was in fact with the usage of `Fs`. Instead, using a temporary array `Fs_` the code works. I explained it in detail in my answer.

Comment: Right, so if `Fs` isn't initialized correctly (e.g. contains a NaN, adding another value to that will result in a NaN). But no "legal" value added to another legal value (that is within valid range for the floating point format chosen) will result in NaN - overflows may do, but I doubt that is actually what happens. I think your `Fs` contains something incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I make the code work without NaNs.

As some commenters pointed out, there could be problems with the initializations. In fact, instead of using directly `Fs` (which is a member of a greater class - this code itself is part of a method), I stored the sums of cosines in a temporary array `Fs_`, declared and initialized inside the method (e.g. like `Scos`): now there are no NaNs anymore.